# I want to give collection name as variable in nlog mongo configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, nlog

This configuration works, but what I want is to dynamically give databaseName = "logDb". So I want the "logDb" value to change while the application is running.

This nlog mongodb config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Mongo" />
  </extensions>
  <targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="Mongo"
            name="mongoCustom"
            includeDefaults="false"
            connectionString="mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017"
            databaseName="logDb"
            collectionName="DefaultLogDocument"
            cappedCollectionSize="26214400">
      <field name="Date" layout="${longdate}" bsonType="DateTime" />
      <field name="Level" layout="${level}"/>
      <field name="Message" layout="${message}" />
      <field name="Logger" layout="${logger}"/>
      <field name="Location" layout="${callsite:className=true:methodName=true}" />
      <field name="Exception" layout="${exception:format=tostring}" />
      <field name="ThreadId" layout="${threadid}" bsonType="Int32" />
      <field name="ThreadName" layout="${threadname}" />
      <field name="ProcessId" layout="${processid}" bsonType="Int32" />
      <field name="ProcessName" layout="${processname:fullName=true}" />
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <!--Rules Section-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="mongoCustom" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this issue: https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo/issues/39

Comment: Absolutely, the problem is solved, thanks